# Choose variable based on weighted probability

Tags: random, google-apps-script, probability

I have a list of variables with their weighted probability, as below:

```
Cloudy: 0.25
Sunny and warm: 0.25
Dry and cold: 0.125
Wet and cold: 0.25
Wet and warm: 0.375
Stormy/rainy: 0
```

In google sheets I am using the following function to select a variable based on their cumulative probabilities

```
=INDEX('WeatherChoices'!A2:A7,COUNTIF('WeatherChoices'!D2:D7,"<="&RAND())+1)
```

Where A2:A7 is the list of weather types and D2:D7 is the cumulative probabilities.

I am now trying to replicate this as a google script function but can't figure out an alternative to nested IF statements. I.e. generate a random number and if between two of the cumulative values choose the variable.

Is there are more elegant way of doing this in one step?

I have looked through the documentation but couldn't find anything other than the `.random()` function.

Comment: `random()` Is what's going to work best, have you considered a `switch` statement? it looks more streamlined than a bunch of `if/else` statements, is that acceptable?

Comment: No I hadn't come across that before. It does look a lot simpler in terms of readability. Thanks for the recommendation. Ill have a go at implementing it this afternoon.

Comment: How does your formula work? `Rand()` creates a random number between 0 and 1. If rand()  results in anything above 0.5, countif  always returns 6  and index always returns `Stormy/rainy`

Comment: Just realised I didn't mention that for the google sheets function I actually use the cumulative probability, so in the example above it wouldn't ever return Storm/rainy. Ill edit now to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function test(){
  var number= 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    number = Math.random().toFixed(3);
    switch(true){
      case number > 0 && number < 0.375:
        Logger.log("wet");
        break;
      case number > 0.376:
        Logger.log("something else");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

This is a very simple version of what you'll need, but it shows you how to use the switch in App Script. You will need to set each case for the different probabilities you have, similar to with `if` statements, but this looks much more organized. If you have any doubts, [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) will give you the basics, and [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-switch-statement-in-javascript) will show you how to set more complex cases.